# Перехват stdout и stderr в С++

Tags: c++, кроссплатформенность

У меня есть задание. Написать приложение на С++ , которое принимает на вход имя файла, который надо запустить это может быть cmd, bash, exe и т.д., и перехватить его out и err. После завершения работы, записать всё в текстовый файл. Оно должно работать на Windows и Linux.

Мой личный вариант написать вот так `system("argv[1]>output.txt")`, но не уверен, что это правильно будет. Мб есть еще варианты как это сделать?

Comment: Boost.Process..

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните понятнее кто кого должен запускать и записывать.

Comment: @Cerbo, шас более понятно?

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/process.html

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , Так понимаю вы предлагаете отдельную библиотеку скачать т.к. у меня последняя версия VS стоит и нету boost, тогда мне этот вариант не подходит.

Comment: Именно так. Почему нет?

Comment: Так в чем задание? Вам действительно разрешается использовать примитивные трюки вроде `system("... > output.txt")`? Или все таки это задание на пайпы?

Comment: Для реализации в \*nix придется почитать *manpages*: `pipe`, `fork`, `dup`, `execl`, `close`, `waitpid` (может что и упустил...) . В винде не пишу (надеюсь кто-нибудь вам посоветует что именно читать)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , нельзя её использовать.

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы оба потока перекинуть нужно подправить :

`system((std::string(argv[1])+" 1> output.txt 2>&1").c_str());`

. Так например работает **bash**.